# How to get which indexed values contained in a field with ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 500 profiles, with 2 fields: name and description.

For `description`, it contains other profiles' name. I want to use ElasticSearch to get which profiles got mentioned in each profiles so that I can show them as related profiles.

I know how to get profiles using one profile's name and search for other's description, however in many case one profile will mention other profiles' name not bi-direction.

i.e.:
`A mentions B` but `B does not mention A`.

How to get related profiles by one's description to search for names but not the other way round? Is it possible to get it done with ElasticSearch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want something like a relational join and it's not possible in ES. So the way is to fetch the desc, parse the contained profiles and then make a query. You can also try to explore new ES graph plugin